# image can not load using openshift cloud server

Tags: image, environment-variables, openshift

I using openshift cloud server to host my web-app. I am uploading image into the 'app-root/data/photos/' directory using path variable. Its working properly.

```
$path=$_ENV["OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR"].'photos/'.$photo_name;
```

But when i reloaded that saved image in my web-app using same path, it is not loaded.

```
<img src="{{$_ENV["OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR"].'photos/'.$photo_name}}" height="250px" width="250px"/>
```

what am i do to load that image??

Answer (score 1):

The app-root/data directory is not public by default (no web access).

You can create a symlink to overcome this as outlined here: https://community.jboss.org/people/ozizka/blog/2013/01/06/openshift--how-to-make-uploaded-files-public